# How to reload Views When User Click on tabs?

Tags: iphone, tabs

Hello I am using a tab bar application.

I want to reload a view when user presses on any of tab button.

if user presses first button of tab bar,
first view is loaded only once.

i need when ever user presses first tab bar button,
view must be reloaded.

this is required, due to following reason
in first view -  i have list of employees
& in second view - i have add screen of employees

after adding an employee, it is obvious that user will click on tab bar button one
to see newly added record.

but view is not loaded again,

so, i need to reload entire view

that is  -viewDidLoad{ } method should be invoked every time.

please help me.

I will be thank full.

Comment: Tim, view is loaded just once,
try it.
i want to load view every time whenever tab button is pressed.

Comment: Tim, tab bar - don't even go to view Will Appear Section.

Comment: I disagree - I have an application that uses a UITabBarController, and it calls viewWillAppear whenever I change tabs. Try this: `- (void)viewWillAppear { NSLog(@"view will appear"); [super viewWillAppear]; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't count on `viewDidLoad` getting called every time a view appears. Instead, you should move the code into `viewWillAppear` (or better yet, move it into a separate method and call that method from `viewWillAppear`).

For example:

```
- (void)loadEmployeeData {
    // Your code here
}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];

    [self loadEmployeeData];
}
```

In general, you should put loading code that only needs to run once (but may run multiple times) into `viewDidLoad`, code that needs to run every time a view is shown in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, and code that can run even before the view loads or *absolutely* needs to only run once into `initWithNibName:bundle:`.